# How can I merge two dataframes based on range of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames: `df1` and `df2`

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['2024-01-01 04:00:00', '2023-02-02 20:00:00'],
        'id':['a_1', 'a_2']

    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [
            '2024-01-01 4:00:00', '2024-01-01 05:00:00',
            '2024-01-01 06:00:00', '2024-01-01 07:00:00',
            '2024-01-01 08:00:00', '2024-01-01 09:00:00',
            '2023-02-02 21:00:00', '2023-02-02 23:00:00',
         ]
    }
)
```

And this is the expected output. I want to merge `id` from `df1` to `df2`:

```
                    a  id
0 2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1  
1 2024-01-01 05:00:00  a_1
2 2024-01-01 06:00:00  a_1
3 2024-01-01 07:00:00  a_1
4 2024-01-01 08:00:00  NaN
5 2024-01-01 09:00:00  NaN
6 2023-02-02 21:00:00  a_2
7 2023-02-02 23:00:00  a_2
```

If you are familiar with candlesticks, `df1.a` is 4 hour candlestick. For example `df1.a.iloc[0]`is:

2024-01-01 04:00:00

2024-01-01 05:00:00

2024-01-01 06:00:00

2024-01-01 07:00:00

Basically it is a range from `df1.a.iloc[0]` to `df1.a.iloc[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=3)`. And I want to `merge` these ids by the range of hours that they cover.

This is my attempt but I don't know how to `merge` by range of dates:

```
df1['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.a)
df2['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.a)
df1['b'] = df1.a + pd.Timedelta(hours=3)
```

Comment: How can `2023-01-01 05:00:00` match `a_1`? It is not the same year

Comment: @mozway typo! I fix it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `tolerance`:

```
df1['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['a'])
df2['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['a'])

out = (pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index().sort_values(by='a'),
                     df1.sort_values(by='a'), on='a',
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta(hours=3)
                    )
         .set_index('index').reindex(df2.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
                    a   id
0 2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1
1 2024-01-01 05:00:00  a_1
2 2024-01-01 06:00:00  a_1
3 2024-01-01 07:00:00  a_1
4 2024-01-01 08:00:00  NaN
5 2024-01-01 09:00:00  NaN
6 2023-02-02 21:00:00  a_2
7 2023-02-02 23:00:00  a_2
```

Comment: that was a very fast upvote, whoever did it, make sure to read the answer first ;)

Comment: I did it :) because you are my hero :)

Comment: @x_Amir_x I appreciate this, but make sure to only vote after you read (and agreed with) the answer otherwise this might be seen as fraudulent voting and cancelled.

Comment: I know that. Next time. I really want to share a part of the profit that I am making on my project with you. I hope I can contact you. Probably a year or so. Without your help I couldn't move forward. I learned a lot from your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use IntervalIndex

```
(df1.set_axis(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
    pd.to_datetime(df1['a']),
    pd.to_datetime(df1['a']) + pd.Timedelta('4H'),closed='left'))
.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df2['a']))
.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
                     a   id
0  2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1
1  2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1
2  2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1
3  2024-01-01 04:00:00  a_1
4                  NaN  NaN
5                  NaN  NaN
6  2023-02-02 20:00:00  a_2
7  2023-02-02 20:00:00  a_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this solution out and it should work for you. Creating a new column which represents the end of your range for df1 will allow you to use a function to iterate over each row and then check whether or not your id matches.

Creating the new column:

```
df1['end'] = df1['a'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=3)
```

Iterating over each row:

```html
def get matching_id(row):
  for _, r in df1.iterrows():
    if r['a'] <= row['a'] <= r['end']:
      return r['id']
  return pd.NA
```

Apply the function:

```
df2['id'] = df2.apply(get_matching_id, axis = 1)
```

This should assign your ids to each row in df2 if it falls within the range we created. This is probably not super performant for large scale pandas, and the fact that we're doing candlesticks analysis here makes me think that maybe volume is an issue, but if so just let me know and we'll work it out. There's very similar solutions to be had if we need to migrate to Spark dataframes.